# Convert MOV to WEBM, With alpha Channel, without losing quality

Tags: ffmpeg, alpha, webm

I need to do the followning conversation. I did it successfully trough FFmpeg, but It seems like it doesn't matter which --flag I am using the quality reduces dramatically, the video is not 'sharp' .
I used

```
ffmpeg -i ee.mov -vf unpremultiply=inplace=1 -c:v libvpx-vp9 -b:v 0 -crf 31 square-prefffmult.webm
```

[image]

Comment: Try lower values of `crf` - the result is going to be larger file with better quality.